# Loading generic webpages with html href

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to load a generic webpage with a dropdown menu by appending parameters on to a url string and then using the html "a" tag to load the page. Currently I have this as a redirection for my dropdown:

> ```
>              <li class="dropdown">
>                     <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" id="dropdown">
>                        <li class="dropdown-header">Algorithums</li>
>                        <li><a href= "graphFacebook.html?me=facebook_1">Layer One</a>
>                        </li>
>                        <li><a href= "graphFacebook.html?me=facebook_2">Layer Two</a>
>                        </li>
>                        <li><a href= "graphFacebook.html?me=facebook_2">Layer Three</a>
>                        </li>
>                         <li><a href= "graphFacebook.html?me=facebook_3">Layer Four</a>
>                        </li>
>                        <li class="divider"></li>
>                       <li class="dropdown-header">Display Options</li>
>
>                        <li><a href=# >Refresh</a>
>                       </li>
>                       <li><a href= graphFacebook.html>Clear</a>
>                       </li>
>                   </ul>
>               </li>
>           </ul>
> ```

However, I need to be able to do this:

>

> new_url = "graphGeneric.html?me=param_1&param_2"
>
> ```
> <li><a href=new_url> Layer Two</a> </li>
> ```

How would I do this combination of html and javascript? Currently, if I set href = new_url it directs me to a page titled new_url, but instead I need it to access the value new_url is set to.

Comment: Hi user3821820, welcome to SO! Typically, users on here will be disinclined to help answer questions unless the original poster has provided some code to demonstrate (s)he has made some effort. Do you have code we could look at (preferably using a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))?

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't exactly lump them all together into one parameter like that, unless you intend to split the string apart on the receicing page.  What you should do should look like this:

```
    var new_url = "graphGeneric.html?"; 
    var paramNum = 0;

    function addParams(theValue) {
    new_url += "me" + paramNum + "="+ theValue +"&";
paramNum++;
    }
```

So, everytime you wish to append another parameter to your new_url, you call that function and tell it what value to add. It will generate something like:

graphGeneric.html?me_0=this&me_1=thisAlso&

Indeffinitely up the line.

Comment: You forgot to increment the `paramNum` param. You should put `paramNum++;` in there.